# INFORMATICA: Place a column value from one record onto another record in the same set

Tags: informatica

```
CURRENT RESULTS:                        
TYP RECORD_ID   IOC MONEY   OC  EN          EN_AM
BS  A1212001    01  2051    087 00000000    000000
EN  A1212001    00  0019    000 000H0203    010000
EN  A1212001    00  0095    000 000H0228    000100
EN  A1212001    00  0103    000 000H0229    000025
EN  A1212001    00  0084    000 000H0318    000015
CR  A1212001    01  0000    087 00000000    000000
CR  A1212001    05  0000    080 00000000    000000

DESIRED RESULTS:                        
TYP RECORD_ID   IOC MONEY   OC  EN          EN_AM
BS  A1212001    01  2070    087 000H0203    010000
EN  A1212001    00  0095    000 000H0228    000100
EN  A1212001    00  0103    000 000H0229    000025
EN  A1212001    00  0084    000 000H0318    000015
CR  A1212001    05  0000    080 00000000    000000
```

I need to check to see if there is one or more EN records and if so, ensure that the EN and EN_AM get placed on the BS record
as well as have the EN record's money added to the BS record.
I also need to drop duplicate CR records that match the BS record in IOC and OC.

I've tried creating a variable based on EN values and attempted to place on BS record in both an agg and an exp after agg and that didn't work. 
I've tried setting current as next with original input port as current, in that order with output port as next in both an agg and an exp after agg and that didn't work.
I've also tried the FIRST() function in an agg with IIF in exp after agg and that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you determine which EN record to merge with BS record? From the example it appears only the EN record just after BS gets merged. Is that so?

Comment: If count EN >= 1

Comment: It can be any EN record as long as its EN and EN_AM does not contain all zeros.